# CoreBluetooth scan and get RSSI from bluetooth devices in certain period when app work in background

Tags: swift, background, core-bluetooth

I want to scan bluetooth devices and get RSSI values when app in background. The following code work when app in foreground but not working background.

```
func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager,
                             didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral,
                             advertisementData: [String : Any],
                             rssi RSSI: NSNumber)
{

    print("RSSI: \(RSSI.intValue)")
    print("Device: \(peripheral.name)")
}

func centralManagerDidUpdateState(_ central: CBCentralManager) {

    if central.state == .poweredOn{

        central.scanForPeripherals(withServices:nil,options: [CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey : true])

    }
}
```

Comment: You can't scan for `nil` services in the background - You need to scan for a specific service.  You also can't use the duplicates key in the background either; you can only get a single discovery notification for a peripheral while scanning in the background,.